# Why a String is not recognized as an Object

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm compiling my java project with java 4 using GNU Make which does not support generics.

Here's my little code causing the error :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
  if (text.charAt(i) > 127) {
      buffer.append("\"");
      String charValue = asciiToNascMap.get(String.valueOf((int)text.charAt(i)));
      buffer.append(String.format(";CHR$(%d);\"", charValue));
     } else {
         buffer.append(text.charAt(i));
       }
   }

   private static Map<String, String>   asciiToNascMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
  asciiToNascMap.put("232", "125");//è
  asciiToNascMap.put("233", "123");//é
  asciiToNascMap.put("224", "64");//à
  asciiToNascMap.put("231", "92");//ç
  asciiToNascMap.put("199", "180");//Ç
  asciiToNascMap.put("234", "193");//ê
}
```

I'm getting this error :

```
 Printer.java:319: error:Cannot find method "java/lang/String.format(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)"
```

Here's the signature of the String.format method :

```
 /**
 * Returns a formatted string using the specified format string and
 * arguments.
 *
 * <p> The locale always used is the one returned by {@link
 * java.util.Locale#getDefault() Locale.getDefault()}.
 *
 * @param  format
 *         A <a href="../util/Formatter.html#syntax">format string</a>
 *
 * @param  args
 *         Arguments referenced by the format specifiers in the format
 *         string.  If there are more arguments than format specifiers, the
 *         extra arguments are ignored.  The number of arguments is
 *         variable and may be zero.  The maximum number of arguments is
 *         limited by the maximum dimension of a Java array as defined by
 *         <cite>The Java&trade; Virtual Machine Specification</cite>.
 *         The behaviour on a
 *         <tt>null</tt> argument depends on the <a
 *         href="../util/Formatter.html#syntax">conversion</a>.
 *
 * @throws  IllegalFormatException
 *          If a format string contains an illegal syntax, a format
 *          specifier that is incompatible with the given arguments,
 *          insufficient arguments given the format string, or other
 *          illegal conditions.  For specification of all possible
 *          formatting errors, see the <a
 *          href="../util/Formatter.html#detail">Details</a> section of the
 *          formatter class specification.
 *
 * @throws  NullPointerException
 *          If the <tt>format</tt> is <tt>null</tt>
 *
 * @return  A formatted string
 *
 * @see  java.util.Formatter
 * @since  1.5
 */
public static String format(String format, Object ... args) {
    return new Formatter().format(format, args).toString();
}
```

Comment: Well, you said you are using JDK 1.4, but the format method in the description says "since 1.5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `String.format` in Java 1.4.

Try:

```
buffer.append(";CHR$(").append(Integer.valueOf(charValue)).append(");\"");
```

Answer (score 5):

The method you are trying to use is not available in Java 1.4. See the `@since` tag in your posted commentary. It says `@since  1.5` meaning it was intoduced in Java 1.5.

Comment: so is there an equivalent in Java 4?

Comment: There is nothing called "Java 4".  It is Java 1.4.  Sun start to call it Java 5 starting from Java 1.5.  However, from 1.2 to 1.4, they are all Java 2.  And, no, there is no alternative of String.fromat before Java 5, because there is no vararg support before Java 5

Comment: @AdrianShum I didn't not know that since I started with Java 1.5 ;-) Thanks for explaining. I corrected that little detail in my answer.

Comment: @AmiraGL I don't know a fitting substitude either. Any possibility you can go to a newer Java version? Using Java 1.4 could even be a security issue.

Comment: @AndréStannek: See my answer, but you are right. Java 1.4 is OLD

Answer (score 2):

`String.format` is not available in Java 1.4. This is indicated in the text you posted in the `@since` tag. varargs support was not added until Java 5, which is why it probably wasn't added until then. People have created `C printf-style` libraries, however.

See these links:

http://www.sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/introduction.htm
http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lloyd/java/doc/cformat.html